# Infinite scroll dosn't have jQuery or JavaScript effects when masonry new elements appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code that makes this parallax effect on my elements with masonry.

I have added the infinite-scroll JS to my page but when the new element appear they don't transition with the original elements. I think it has to do with the document ready function on click but I don't know how to implement it. Here's the code

This is for the parallax `<div>` element:

```
 $.fn.moveIt = function(){
  var $window = $(window);
  var instances = [];

  $(this).each(function(){
    instances.push(new moveItItem($(this)));
  });

  window.onscroll = function(){
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    instances.forEach(function(inst){
      inst.update(scrollTop);
    });
  }
}
var moveItItem = function(el){
  this.el = $(el);
  this.speed = parseInt(this.el.attr('data-scroll-speed'));
};

moveItItem.prototype.update = function(scrollTop){
  this.el.css('transform', 'translateY(' + -(scrollTop / this.speed) + 'px)');
};

// Initialization
$(function(){
  $('[data-scroll-speed]').moveIt();
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".card").css({ translate: [60,30] }); 






and this is for the infinite scroll 

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.grid').infiniteScroll({
  // options
  path: '.next',
  append: '.grid-item',
  history: false,
});
</script>
```

Also when the new content loads they don't have the masonry effect on them.

Comment: Sure...and there are lots of tutorials on the web for this. Stackoverflow is not a *"how to"* tutorial service

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the best place for this sort of question.  If you've tried to code a site like that, post your code and we can help you troubleshoot or optimize it.

Comment: Thank you all, although this website isn't for how to's as you've said. I think it would be nicer to give links to these tutorials rather than voting the post down. Believe me iv'e searched everywhere that's why i came here.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this [Cdepen](https://codepen.io/JTParrett/pen/BkDie) - Found on Google Search

Hope this would help.

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box" data-scroll-speed="2">S</div>
    <div class="box" data-scroll-speed="3">C</div>
    <div class="box" data-scroll-speed="6">R</div>
    <div class="box" data-scroll-speed="5">O</div>
    <div class="box" data-scroll-speed="9">L</div>
    <div class="box" data-scroll-speed="4">L</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    @import bourbon

body
  font-family: arial, sans-serif

.content
  height: 5000px

.wrapper
  +display(flex)
  +justify-content(center)
  +align-items(center)
  +size(100% 100vh)
  +position(fixed, 0px null null 0px)

.box
  +flex(none)
  +size(100px)
  line-height: 100px
  text-align: center
  font-size: 25px
  color: #fff
  background: #ff8330

  &:nth-of-type(2)
    background: #E01B5D
  &:nth-of-type(3)
    background: #30FFFF
  &:nth-of-type(4)
    background: #B3FF30
  &:nth-of-type(5)
    background: #308AFF
  &:nth-of-type(6)
    background: #1BE059
```

JQuery:

```
   $.fn.moveIt = function(){
  var $window = $(window);
  var instances = [];

  $(this).each(function(){
    instances.push(new moveItItem($(this)));
  });

  window.onscroll = function(){
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    instances.forEach(function(inst){
      inst.update(scrollTop);
    });
  }
}

var moveItItem = function(el){
  this.el = $(el);
  this.speed = parseInt(this.el.attr('data-scroll-speed'));
};

moveItItem.prototype.update = function(scrollTop){
  this.el.css('transform', 'translateY(' + -(scrollTop / this.speed) + 'px)');
};

// Initialization
$(function(){
  $('[data-scroll-speed]').moveIt();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but in my case i want the whole body to be like a lazy scroll kind of thing when scrolling through the blog post. Once again i am so thankful for your comment

Comment: add the jquery code for every element on page. That would help.

Comment: can i give you my website link